# How to get an Answer from a web service after sending Get request in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, nsurlconnection

I'm a novice in iOS developing, and have some problems with understanding web service organization. I want to send a Get query to the URL. And I do it so:

```
-(BOOL) sendLoginRequest{
NSString *getAction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"action=%@&username=%password=%@",@"login",self.log.text, self.pass.text];
NSString *getUserName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@",self.log.text];
NSString *getPassword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@",self.pass.text];

NSData *getDataAction = [getAction dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *getLengthAction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [getDataAction length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:http://www.site.fi/api/"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:getLengthAction forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:getLengthAction];

self.urlConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];

NSAssert(self.urlConnection != nil, @"Failure to create URL connection.");

// show in the status bar that network activity is starting
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}
```

the answer may be "true" or "false"

but how can I take this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define next methods to get answer:

1. Start connection: `[self.urlConnection start];`
2. Check server response:

   `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`
3. Collect data that servers sends you:

   `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`
4. Be sure to manage errors:

   `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`
5. Check received data:

   `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection`

To be more sure that you correctly understood me check [NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Send `[self.urlConnection start];` and implement the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods to receive the response.  Alternatively use `ASIHTTPRequest` and the block handlers, which to my way of thinking are much easier to write for beginners, provided you don't need to run on iOS pre-4.1.

You will gather the data returned as NSData; just convert that to a string, and either call boolValue on the string (check the docs for its rather strange tests), or use a specific set of your own tests.